# Can't add pass to Wallet in iOS Simulator, but nothing is logged

Tags: ios, wallet

I've created a static `pkpass` file using the signpass application that Apple provides. According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW1), I should be able to drag a pass into the iOS Simulator window and either the pass should be added or

> errors are logged to the system log, which you can view with the Console app.

While the pass appears file in Finder while double clicking, dragging it to the simulator opens the Wallet app but doesn't add it; in addition nothing appears in the Console to show errors. Is there any way to figure out what is wrong with my pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why nothing was being logged in Console…apparently Apple was only telling half of the truth. The system log that pertains to the simulator is actually *seperate* from the computer's system log, and is located at `/Users/[Your username]/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[Simulator UUID]/system.log`, and can be found by selecting Debug > Open System Log in the Simulator (or by pressing ⌘/). Errors will appear there (in my case, signpass was adding a .DS_Store to the zip even though the directory didn't have one).